# Which Steps to perform after changing Service Account password from Active Directory?

Tags: 2013, service-account, password, managed-account

I have one requirement where I have to reset password of Service Accounts and SQL Administrator account of SharePoint from Active Directory. Now after changing these password what should be my next steps so that my SharePoint is up and running without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must change Sharepoint Service account pass in managed account!
You can use this powershell:
Set-SpManagedAccount -identity domain\service_account -Password newpassword

or You can do it in central admin:
Security->General Security -> Configure managed accounts 
Edit your service account and check Change Password Now.
So enter new value and so ok this dialog!
Sql Admin account depend on your infrastructure,but usually it change automatically!